# Refactoring a huge class to lots of tiny classes

Tags: refactoring, coding-style

I have a wonderful opportunity to refactor out old and "smelly" code
into a much better designed class family.

I have the basic design skeleton figured out, implemented and **tested**.

However, I reached a point where I have a big "Manager" class
that does manage what it is supposed to manage (lets suppose some tricky task queue),
but it is also responsible for some other stuff, which were not my first intention for this class.

Creating a set of new classes

```
class OperationAPerformer
{
    void PerformA(input){...}
}

class OperationBPerformer
{
    void PerformB(input){...}
}
```

feels like not the right solution.
Keeping the logic for OperationA, OperationB in the manager class
seems to inflate the Manager class with no good design reason

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Ok, so I can't post all my code here
but basic design (or skeleton)

```
InitEventHandler  
SubmitEventHandler  
CancelEventHandler  
SuccessEventHandler  
FailureEventHandler  
ProgressReportedEventHandler  
TimeOutEventHandler
```

...
The event handlers update some parameters
and do some management work like after failure recovery,
UI parameters update and the like..

OperationA and OperationB are related, but make up for lots of code
that disguises the main skeleton of the class

Related Ops
SaveProducts()
   SaveStepA
   SaveStepB
...

ValidateResponses
    ValidatePartA
    ValidatePartB
...

Creating a class like

```
class Validator
{
   public bool Validate(Response resp) {...}
   private bool PartA(...){...}
   private bool PartB(...){...}
}
```

seems inappropriate because the class is only a set of related methods...
is it enough justification to create a class?

Comment: This really isn't enough information for us to have much concrete advice.  Post some more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Size itself isn't a desideratum; it's just a "smell", a reason to investigate whether you should change the code.

The purpose of a class is not to reduce file size.  It is supposed to be the representation of the organizing principle of your code.  If the different operations naturally form categories (ideally, because they are functionally cohesive,  as Pangea suggests, but otherwise for any sound, articulatable reason), then break it up into separate manager classes.

Other ideas:

If the decision mechanism is data-driven, consider a functional map:

```
interface Performer { public void perform(InputClass input); };
Map<String,  Performer> choices = new HashMap<String,  Performer>();
choices.put("choiceA", 
            new Performer() { public void perform(InputClass input) {
                // ... do action A
            });
choices.put("choiceB", 
            new Performer() { public void perform(InputClass input) {
                // ... do action B
            });
```

If the decision is made by code that is closely tied to the code that performs the action, you could re-think "perform" to mean "perform if you can, tell me if you can't":

```
interface Performer { public boolean perform(InputClass input); };
List<Performer> pipeline = new LinkedList<Performer>();
pipeline.add(new Performer() { public void perform(InputClass input) {
// ... do action A if you can
});
pipeline.add( new Performer() { public void perform(InputClass input) {
// ... do action B if you can
});
```

Either way, you can seal the configuration inside the manager, expose it to the main function, even drive it from a config file.

If none of the above is true, and there are simple a large, fixed number of things your manager has to do, consider biting the bullet and just letting the manager class swell up with a lot of small static functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can break the [GOD manager clas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)s into multiple "use case" manager classes i.e. a separate manager class for each use case. This way each manager class is functionally cohesive and there is only one reason for the manager class to change (single responsibility principle).

And if you are having hard time to break it into smaller classes then it might be a sign that it is already cohesive.

Comment: The manager class is primarily used to manage a task queue and not as a GOD class. 
There are no apparent use cases, all the operations must be performed. but if I leave the operations in the manager, it won't follow the single responsibilty principle

Comment: post the class here...otherwise it is hard to tell